# I need to take data from input and create a Student class with Students grades in an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, oop, arraylist

I'm having problem with creating a student class.
My input file is like:

```
3 //number of exams
Audrey 7 28 1
Eddie 27 19 7
Addison 6 23 31
Stephanie 29 21 7
Laura 19 30 17
```

I need to create a student class with one constructor something like 
`public Student(String name, int[] Student Grades)`.

Problem is I can't create a student with 3 grades,
I need to create:
 student Audrey with grades [7, 28, 1] or Student 1 Name Audrey Grades[ 7,28,1]

I tried but can't put first 3 variable for first Student.

How can I do this?

Updated My work:

```
File file = new File("info1.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
int []grade = new int[3];
int counter = 0;
Student[] students = new Student[9];

while(input.hasNext()) {

    String Studentread= input.nextLine();
    for (int i = 0; i < grade.length; i++) {
        grade [i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println(grade.toString());
    students[counter] = new Student(Studentread, grade);
    System.out.println(students[counter].getName() + " " + students[counter].getStudentGrades());
    counter++;

    input.close();
}
```

Class Student:

```
private String Name;
public int [] StudentGrades;

public Student(String name, int[] StudentGrades) {

this.Name = name;
    this.StudentGrades = StudentGrades;
}

public String getName() {
    return Name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    Name = name;
}

public int[] getStudentGrades() {
    return StudentGrades;
}
public void setStudentGrades(int[] studentGrades) {
   StudentGrades = studentGrades;
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO @Alihan - please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Pay attention to the correct code indentations (see my edit).

Comment: Also show your you create `input` is it an iterator on the lines of your file? This: `int[] Grades = input.nextInt()` probably doesn't compile, `nextInt()` returns an int, you try to assign it to an array.

Comment: That is my main problem. I cant put integers that comes after Student names to Grades array. i need to do this automatically. its easy when i do not read from file.

Comment: @AlihanAydın You need to use a loop and call `input.nextInt();` 3 times, that will give you 3 ints, and you can put them in your grades array

Comment: I tried that but didn't worked well. Thank you for answering.

Comment: Share your whole code, I'll help you fix it

Comment: Thank you. I'm unable to share my code right now. Will share when i get home. I shared main class  in my question already. Only student class left.

Comment: @AlihanAydın How do you read the file? You didn't share that code

Comment: With scanner file, sorry didn't see that

Comment: I shared my all work  now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to read the file line by line rather that token by token with a `Scanner`.
This is because each line has a meaning in your file. and directly match to a `Student`

I commented the code so you understand what every line is doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    // read all the lines of your file
    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("info1.txt"));

    // first line is the number of exams
    int nbExams = Integer.valueOf(lines.get(0).trim());

    // remove first line, now each line is a student
    lines.remove(0);
    int nbStudents = lines.size();

    Student[] students = new Student[nbStudents];
    for(int iStudents = 0; iStudents<nbStudents; iStudents++) {
        String line = lines.get(iStudents);

        // split your line on spaces
        String[] tokens = line.split(" ");

        // first is name
        String studentName = tokens[0];

        // next are studentGrades
        int[] grades = new int[nbExams];
        for(int i=0; i<nbExams; i++) {
            grades[i] = Integer.valueOf(tokens[i+1]);
        }

        students[iStudents] = new Student(studentName, grades);
    }

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(students));
}
```

**NOTES:**

- Always use lowerCase for the first letter of your variables (`studentGrades`, not `StudentGrades`). Uppercase are reserved for classes and interfaces
- Add a `toString` method to your student class, so you can print them nicely
- You don't need setters on your `Student` class as you provide all the data in the constructor.

You `Student` class should look like this:

```
class Student {
    private String name;
    private int[] studentGrades;

    public Student(String name, int[] studentGrades) {
        this.name = name;
        this.studentGrades = studentGrades;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int[] getStudentGrades() {
        return studentGrades;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Student{" +
                  "name=" + name + ", " +
                  "studentGrades=" + Arrays.toString(studentGrades) +
                "}";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but still got error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "Audrey 7 28 1"at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:983)
 at Ass.main(Ass.java:15)

Comment: do you have the number of exams in your file? the number on the first line. seems like your first line is `Audrey 7 28 1`

Comment: Sorry i forgot i changed that. But i still got error that says :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1

Comment: okay it works now. But how can i view student's information? Like student1.getgrades or getname. Thank you.

Comment: `students[0].getName()`, `students[0].getStudentGrades()[0]`, `students[0].getStudentGrades()[1]`, `students[0].getStudentGrades()[2]` etc..

Answer (score 0):

You can read line by line and split the line into array using space delimiter. Or parse the red line by spaces.

Comment: Please try to explain your answer with some code. It will be much helpful to understand.

Comment: Where can i get an example of that?

Comment: The @Bentaye code explains what I mean in the above solutions.